MikTex app no longer opening/can't update or install new packages
I use Ubuntu 22.04 and MikTex for Latex. In the past, I have been able to both install new packages on the fly in VS Code (i.e. \usepackage{12many} will automatically pop up MikTex if I don't have 12many installed), and I can search for the MikTex app and open it up to manually install packages from there.
I'm not sure when this problem started occurring, but when I look up the MikTex app via search, then click on it, nothing happens, and I just get an error and an Ubuntu pop-up that says "do you want to send issue to developer." When I try to install packages on the fly in VS Code, nothing happens and I just get an error in my Latex compilation.
I tried to follow the instructions of this post on the Tex Stack Exchange, but I can't right-click to find the location of the executable. Searching for miktex in my files app yields many executables, but running each one doesn't do anything.
I am trying to avoid deleting and reinstalling the whole MikTex distribution.

I ended up completely uninstalling MiKTeX and installing TeXLive, and I am no longer having issues with installing packages.
